# How to process all products defined in a project (ConTeXt)

Tags: compiling, context, context-mkiv

If I have

**project.tex**

```
\startproject project
\product one
\product two
\endproject
```

and the corresponding product files,
is there an easy way to process all product files,
so I get

**one.pdf**
 **two.pdf**

at once?

Comment: No, apart from manually running all the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the project structure incorrectly.  Projects are not wrappers for products, but usually contain a list of environments which are then included in a product.

Imagine you had a long list of environments for the page layout, the colour theme, the bibliography macros, and mathematical macros for your document.  You wouldn't want to repeat the whole list in every component, which is why you collect this list in a project.  For example

#### `proj-mag.tex`

```
\startproject *
  \environemnt env-design
  \environemnt env-layout
  \environemnt env-biblio
  \environemnt env-mathem
\stopproject
```

#### `p-issue1.tex`

```
\project proj-mag
\startproduct *
  \component c-editorial
\stopproduct
```

The file that you run ConTeXt on is `p-issue1.tex`.

Comment: Nonetheless, at project level you can specify products as the OP did (and as it is done in the ConTeXt Wiki [page](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure)); so, it isn't that obvious that you still need something like make if you want to automate compiling a bunch of project-related products.